# Difference between pointers and references in c++

Tags: c++

I so confused about parameter types in C++ I have two functions in following code:

```
void degistir2( int *x, int *y )
{ 
   int gecici;
   gecici = *x; *x = *y;
   *y = gecici;
}
void degistir3( int &x, int &y )
{ 
    int gecici;
    gecici = x; x = y;
    y = gecici;
}
```

What is the difference of these functions? I know the pointers and references but I don't know how it works in above functions.

Comment: You don't know them then... How do the parameter types confuse you?

Comment: Both functions doing exact same work. Right?

Comment: Yes, that's right. [More here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/57483/what-are-the-differences-between-a-pointer-variable-and-a-reference-variable-in).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first example, your function is given a copy of the address of x and y.

In the second example, your function is given the same instance of x and y as the code that function call originates from.

By default, functions receive a copy of the variable being passed to the function. Both of your examples allow you to access the original x and y by different methods.

See 7.2-7.4 of [this guide](http://www.learncpp.com/#Chapter7) for more details and examples.